# Phonegap jQuery Mobile app experiencing random redirects

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I have a Phonegap 2.2 app using native [tab bar](https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-ios-tabbar-plugin) and [navigation bar](https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-ios-navigationbar-plugin) plugins and jQuery Mobile. I generally have no problem navigating through my app, though in certain situations I will open a page, only to be quickly redirected back to the previous page.

I suspect that either the tab bar or jQuery Mobile code (or, more likely, their intersection), is responsible for this bug. I have a multi-page template, in jQuery Mobile's terminology, and am doing navigation programmatically like so:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#page-id')
```

The native tab bar items are configured like so:

```
plugins.tabBar.createItem("contact", "Unused, iOS replaces this text by Contacts", "tabButton:Contacts", {onSelect: function() {
  $.mobile.changePage('#contact')
  plugins.navigationBar.setTitle("Contacts")
}})
```

I'm listening to jQuery Mobile's `pageshow` and `pagehide` events and the page transitions are firing as normal for all the page changes, so it looks like the original page is being loaded normally. Of course, I just don't know *why* I'm getting that second page change, back to the original page.

I suspect that the tab button `onSelect` callback is getting fired again, as the problem seems to mostly be when I go from a page with an accompanying tab bar item to one without, only to get redirected back.

Has anyone encountered this before? Might there be further hooks into jQuery Mobile that I could use to monitor the page state and state changes?

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem. It's not a *phonegap* bug.

I use *JQM* in several contexts : *phonegap*, web mobile and web.

I detected that bug only in web mode (without *phonegap*) in one special situation.

We have a web splash-screen which disappears when everything is initialized via a *changePage* to our home page.

When doing that change too quick (that why I presume it appears only on desktop), we have your random bug too (20%). *JQM* goes back to the previous page (*splashscreen*) and doesn't launch the *pagebeforechange* event.

The only thing that seems to work is to use a `setTimeout()` of 2s (which is huge) to delay the change page.

If someone has an explanation...

Advance Thanks.